# Unpacking a directory into its parent directory

Tags: unix, directory

I've got a directory (`wordpress`) in a folder (the main `html` directory of my website) and I'd like to "unpack" it into the main html directory. That is to say, I'd like to remove the `wordpress` directory and have all its subdirectories be under `/html/` instead of `/html/wordpress/`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cd /html/wordpress
$ mv * ..
$ cd ..
$ rmdir wordpress
```

Do you need something more complicated?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I was unaware of the wildcard... duh! I am a Unix newbie.

Answer (score 1):

```
mv /path/to/html/wordpress/* /path/to/html
rmdir /path/to/html/wordpress
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

```
mv /html/wordpress/* /html
rmdir wordpress
```